# Video player created with Youtube Iframe API stopped working with Chrome v.85

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I'm having problems with using Youtube iframe API with the latest stable version of Chrome (version 85). I know everything used to work a month ago, but now, even following exactly the most basic example found in the Youtube iframe API docs:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

does not work anymore. onReady and onStateChange events arent getting triggerd, and the "player" object is missing most of its functions, for example player.playVideo() is undefined. The problem doesnt occur on any other browser I tested it with, it also only occurs if I'm logged in to my Youtube account while testing this.

I suspect the origin of the problem are the cookies sent with requests from Youtube, as I get this error in the console in the "Issues found" tab:

"Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute"

, while Chrome in version 85 notes mentioned this:

"Rejection of insecure SameSite=None cookies"

It would match the fact that the player works if I'm logged out of Youtube, as Youtube uses these cookies to suggest different videos based on your profile.

I am looking for a workaround at the moment, only thing I could find was that if I created the iframe manually, instead of using the API, I could put "youtube-nocookie" instead of "youtube" in the src of the iframe, but that way I don't have an object I could refer to in order to control the player, for example if I had to create a custom button to pause/play the video. I guess it's mostly on Youtube to fix their API, but is there some way to work around this for now?

Here's a Codepen to illustrate the problem, the code was taken from the Youtube Iframe API docs linked above:

https://codepen.io/Gabielovv/pen/VwadJvg?editors=1111

```
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    console.log("onPlayerReady");
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    console.log("onPlayerStateChange");
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }

  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }

  function playYtVideo() {
    console.log("playYtVideo");
    player.playVideo();
  }
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy. I told myself I could have sworn this was working last week when I was playing around with it. Then I eventually tried incognito and it seemed to work. So yes, as you said, if I'm logged in to youtube, the player doesn't work

Comment: @prawn sounds like a bug with the iframe API, if so, this question should be posted on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) - if isn't posted there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solve from this [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168644309#comment4). It seems that it's a browser issue.

Try those:

- Clear cache including cookies
- Try disabling [chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies](http://chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies) and put it back (worked for me)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, found a couple of other related threads in the issue tracker, problem with this solution is that it requires asking users to change theirs browsers security settings in order to use our site, so not reeealy ideal, but it does seem like the only option until either Google reverts their cookie policy change in the next update, or Youtube changes their API

Comment: Agree that it's not sustainable to have the end-users required to do any changes. So hope that this will be fixed in a way that's transparent for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it, and everything seems to work now, I've also seen people on the Google Issue Tracker saying the same thing, so I guess the issue has been fixed, thanks.

Comment: If the [answer provided by Kim Chouard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63929441/4092887) solved (*and in this case*), helped with your issue, please consider accept it. Thank you.