# YouTube Player API is not working as documented

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

It seems that the YouTube Player API is not working at the moment. The player will initialize properly but none of the methods or events are working.

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="log"></div>
</div>

<script>
    // for convenience
   var isPlayerReady = false;
   var logEl = document.getElementById('log');

   function addToLog(text) {
       logEl.innerHTML = logEl.innerHTML + text + '<br>';
   }

   window.setTimeout(function () {
       if (!isPlayerReady) {
           addToLog('5 seconds have passed and the player has not fired the onReady event. This is a good indication that the API is not working properly.');
       }
   }, 5000);
   
   // from here on, the code is a direct copy of an example from the official docs

   // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
   var tag = document.createElement('script');

   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

   // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
   //    after the API code downloads.
   var player;

   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
       addToLog('onYouTubeIframeAPIReady fired, loading Player');
       player = new YT.Player('player', {
           height: '390',
           width: '640',
           videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
           events: {
               'onReady': onPlayerReady,
               'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
           }
       });
   }

   // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
   function onPlayerReady(event) {
       isPlayerReady = true;
       addToLog('onPlayerReady fired');
       event.target.playVideo();
   }

   // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
   //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
   //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
   var done = false;

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
       addToLog('onPlayerStateChange fired');
       if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
           setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
           done = true;
       }
   }

   function stopVideo() {
       player.stopVideo();
   }
    </script>
```

I created a simple codepen to monitor the issue [here](https://codepen.io/liberat0r/pen/OJNwqye). Most of this example is a direct copy of one of the examples in the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: I see nothing in that codepen that illustrates any sort of error ... what is it you are having an issue with (there's absolutely no errors)

Comment: on loading, I see `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady fired, loading Player
onPlayerReady fired
onPlayerStateChange fired
onPlayerStateChange fired
onPlayerStateChange fired` and the video stops after 6 seconds ...

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for looking at the pen. There is no error whatsoever. Please look at the code: onPlayerReady, the video is supposed to autoplay.

Comment: Oh, that can be overridden by settings in the browser ... I certainly don't allow it

Comment: @JaromandaX that is weird by the way: I do not see `onPlayerStateChange fired` as you mentioned!

Comment: could be your browser - mine is firefox and even checked it using chrome (I feel dirty)

Comment: @JaromandaX clearing cache solved it, check my answer and thank you!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue... not sure what's going on. I'm also using Chrome and clearing the cache doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Same issue on my side, the youtube player on https://www.beatsense.com/limbo isn't load on chrome, started yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EDIT] Found a solve from this [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168644309#comment4). It seems that it's a browser issue.

Try those:

- Clear cache including cookies
- Try disabling [chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies](http://chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies) and put it back (worked for me)

Hope that helps

===

You're not alone! I have code using the `on...` events (`onReady`, etc), that worked a few days ago and suddenly stopped working with no code change.

- It got posted on Google Issue Tracker (see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168644309))
- Here is [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894723/video-player-created-with-youtube-iframe-api-stopped-working-with-chrome-v-85) stating the same issue
- It even trickled down to sub-libraries like `react-youtube` (see [Issue #260](https://github.com/tjallingt/react-youtube/issues/260))

It looks like it started on September 9th, which aligns with a Youtube Data API release (see [revision history for Sept. 9](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history)). But I don't see anything in their list that would compromise the iframe events/functions

That's how I far I got, hope that gives a hint to someone to get to a resolution of this. ‍♂️ Will update this comment as findings arise.