# youtube iframe api not firing events

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

recently the youtube videos in my web application stopped firing the onStateChanged events.  After a bit of investigation I confirmed that the examples in the api documentation also stopped working (see link below).  In the example the border colors of the youtube video should change when the state changes, but they currently do not for me.

It appears that this may have something to do with the recent update to the api on september 9th, but I can't confirm that.  Is anyone else seeing the same behavior?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples

Comment: it seems it's a bug. [Check this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63894723/4092887).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Video player created with Youtube Iframe API stopped working with Chrome v.85](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894723/video-player-created-with-youtube-iframe-api-stopped-working-with-chrome-v-85)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar troubles in my application. Users started to complain on september 9th too.
I my case, video iframe created, but than application lost control of it, and can't stop it through api.
Removing of site data from browser helps. But we need to find a source of a problem.